# Puppet-Dashboard Installation Issues

Tags: puppet, centos6

I tried to install Puppet-Dashboard on CentOS 6.3, but I got the below error.

```
root@abt2adp601~>> yum install puppet-dashboard
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository OS is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository OS-NoArch is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository PuppetLabs-Dependencies is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository PuppetLabs-Dependencies-NoArch is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package puppet-dashboard.noarch 0:1.2.23-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-mysql for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package puppet-dashboard.noarch 0:1.2.23-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-mysql for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-rake.noarch 0:0.8.7-2.1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch (PuppetLabs-NoArch)
           Requires: ruby-mysql
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You may want to read the [instructions on code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Puppetlabs Repo?

I just tested on a Centos 6.3 Vagrant box and it worked fine for me:

```
$ rpm -Uvh --oldpackage --replacepkgs http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/i386/puppetlabs-release-6-11.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/i386/puppetlabs-release-6-11.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.PpkX2S: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 4bd6ec30: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:puppetlabs-release     ########################################### [100%]
$ yum install puppet-dashboard -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.econdc.com
 * extras: mirrors.vooservers.com
 * updates: mirror.econdc.com
puppetlabs-products                                                                                                                                           | 2.5 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-products/primary_db                                                                                                                                | 138 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                                            | 1.9 MB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package puppet-dashboard.noarch 0:1.2.23-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(abi) = 1.8 for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby > 1.8.7 for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-mysql for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/ruby for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(rake) for package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ruby.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6 will be installed
---> Package ruby-libs.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.5 for package: ruby-libs-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686
---> Package ruby-mysql.i686 0:2.8.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-rake.noarch 0:0.8.7-2.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package rubygems.noarch 0:1.3.7-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-rdoc for package: rubygems-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-readline5.i686 0:5.2-17.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package ruby-rdoc.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-irb = 1.8.7.374-3.el6_6 for package: ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ruby-irb.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch                               Version                                       Repository                                       Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 puppet-dashboard                             noarch                             1.2.23-1.el6                                  puppetlabs-products                             4.3 M
Installing for dependencies:
 compat-readline5                             i686                               5.2-17.1.el6                                  base                                            128 k
 ruby                                         i686                               1.8.7.374-3.el6_6                             updates                                         538 k
 ruby-irb                                     i686                               1.8.7.374-3.el6_6                             updates                                         317 k
 ruby-libs                                    i686                               1.8.7.374-3.el6_6                             updates                                         1.6 M
 ruby-mysql                                   i686                               2.8.2-1.el6                                   puppetlabs-deps                                  45 k
 ruby-rdoc                                    i686                               1.8.7.374-3.el6_6                             updates                                         381 k
 rubygem-rake                                 noarch                             0.8.7-2.1.el6                                 base                                            404 k
 rubygems                                     noarch                             1.3.7-5.el6                                   base                                            207 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       9 Package(s)

Total download size: 7.9 M
Installed size: 17 M
Downloading Packages:
(1/9): compat-readline5-5.2-17.1.el6.i686.rpm                                                                                                                 | 128 kB     00:00
(2/9): puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch.rpm                                                                                                               | 4.3 MB     00:02
(3/9): ruby-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686.rpm                                                                                                                        | 538 kB     00:00
(4/9): ruby-irb-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686.rpm                                                                                                                    | 317 kB     00:00
(5/9): ruby-libs-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686.rpm                                                                                                                   | 1.6 MB     00:00
(6/9): ruby-mysql-2.8.2-1.el6.i686.rpm                                                                                                                        |  45 kB     00:00
(7/9): ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686.rpm                                                                                                                   | 381 kB     00:00
(8/9): rubygem-rake-0.8.7-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                  | 404 kB     00:00
(9/9): rubygems-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                        | 207 kB     00:00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                2.2 MB/s | 7.9 MB     00:03
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 4bd6ec30: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
Importing GPG key 0x4BD6EC30:
 Userid : Puppet Labs Release Key (Puppet Labs Release Key) <info@puppetlabs.com>
 Package: puppetlabs-release-6-11.noarch (installed)
 From   : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Installing : compat-readline5-5.2-17.1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                1/9
  Installing : ruby-libs-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                  2/9
  Installing : ruby-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                       3/9
  Installing : ruby-irb-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                   4/9
  Installing : ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                  5/9
  Installing : rubygems-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch                                                                                                                                       6/9
  Installing : rubygem-rake-0.8.7-2.1.el6.noarch                                                                                                                                 7/9
  Installing : ruby-mysql-2.8.2-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                       8/9
  Installing : puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch                                                                                                                              9/9
  Verifying  : rubygem-rake-0.8.7-2.1.el6.noarch                                                                                                                                 1/9
  Verifying  : puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch                                                                                                                              2/9
  Verifying  : ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                  3/9
  Verifying  : ruby-mysql-2.8.2-1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                       4/9
  Verifying  : ruby-libs-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                  5/9
  Verifying  : rubygems-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch                                                                                                                                       6/9
  Verifying  : ruby-irb-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                   7/9
  Verifying  : ruby-1.8.7.374-3.el6_6.i686                                                                                                                                       8/9
  Verifying  : compat-readline5-5.2-17.1.el6.i686                                                                                                                                9/9

Installed:
  puppet-dashboard.noarch 0:1.2.23-1.el6

Dependency Installed:
  compat-readline5.i686 0:5.2-17.1.el6  ruby.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6        ruby-irb.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6  ruby-libs.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6  ruby-mysql.i686 0:2.8.2-1.el6
  ruby-rdoc.i686 0:1.8.7.374-3.el6_6    rubygem-rake.noarch 0:0.8.7-2.1.el6  rubygems.noarch 0:1.3.7-5.el6

Complete!
```